# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: iis

All of the sudden I'm getting the following error on my local web server (Win7 64bit, IIS 7.5).  I've uninstalled & reinstalled IIS locally and it didn't fix it.  IIS is set to start up automatically and I can see that the service has been successfully started.  Upon a fresh reboot if I go into IIS and click on start website I get the following error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  (Exception from HRESULT:  0x80070020

If I try to start debugging on my local website project I get the following error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The underlying connection was closed.  The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Any ideas on what I can try?  I've been doing research on the issue and Microsoft suggest making sure no other service is listening on the same ports.  I've verified that this isn't the issue.

Comment: It happens sometimes, that WAS and W3SVC services hang permanently and the IIS Manager doesn't get control over inner site's 'restart' administrative option, so my suggestion is stop/start/restart the service in the Task Manager Services tab. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the web site to use a port other than 80 (suggest 8080 for example) and see it if will start.  If so that's a sure sign of another service using port 80 (Skype is a common culprit for this).

Comment: It turns out some service i had running locally (KService.exe) was blocking IIS.  Once I stopped that service the problem was solved.  I found out that this service was the problem by using netstat to see what services are listening on the port. Instructions on how to do that are here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973094

Comment: I was able to switch my VS2010 project's port to 8080 (so long as I made sure my IIS site also had bindings set up for that port) and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: No idea why this works - but changing the port worked for me too, thanks. This just happened randomly - no changes had been made to my machine but suddenly my website just stopped working. Odd.

Comment: Ugh, stupid Skype. Gets me every time. I have no idea what genius thought it was okay to use port 80 for Skype.

Answer (score 2):

Application pool's identity password changed?
I know this is an old post, but I can't believe how many times I've been bitten by this.  Some shops use  integrated security for SQL, and often then on your local IIS needs your network login for the application pool.  When your password expires, and you forget to change your password here, start banging your head on the wall... DOH!

Open IIS.  Select Application Pools. Select the application pool used by your app.  Click Advanced Settings... Select Identity, and the little "..." button to update your user/password.