# error IIS 7.5 : Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: asp.net, iis

Visual Studio 2013,IIS 7.5, .Net 4.5

Can not start web application I get error.

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

I try to look same existing errors but it does not help to me.
Many hours I spend for that error, have looked permission Web folder, have reinstalled VS 2013 and IIS,have downloaded update package to VS 2013

```
trust level="Full"
compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"
```

Comment: Try to change the port.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369526/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-underlying-connection-was-close)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the web site to use a port other than 80 (suggest 8080 for example) and see it if will start. If so that's a sure sign of another service using port 80 (Skype is a common culprit for this).

Comment: I am sorry I forgot write in details, I had done than but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

I have added new line to the host file, for site name.

> 127.0.0.1  mvcCms

Then set  name and web directory to IIS.

thanks for answers.